# vertical padding between buttons in a column

Tags: python, tkinter

When I pad the widgets they all just move together on the same frame in 1 big block. I need to be able to separate them and add the padding between each widget on the same frame. This is part of my code I tried:

```
def CreateDisplay(self):

    self.mainwindow = tk.Tk()
    self.mainwindow.geometry("800x600")
    self.mainwindow.wm_title(self.constants.NAME)
    self.mainwindow.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    self.frame_main = tk.Frame(master = self.mainwindow)
    self.frame_title = tk.Frame(master = self.frame_main)
    self.frame_test = tk.Frame(master = self.frame_main)
    self.frame_recentscore = tk.Frame(master = self.frame_main)
    self.frame_help = tk.Frame(master = self.frame_main)
    self.frame_exit = tk.Frame(master = self.frame_main)

    self.frame_main.pack(pady=15)
    self.frame_title.pack(anchor="c")
    self.frame_test.pack(pady=15)
    self.frame_recentscore.pack(pady=15)
    self.frame_help.pack(pady=15)
    self.frame_exit.pack(pady=15)

    self.label_title = tk.Label(self.frame_title, font=("purisa", 20), text="Business Studies Finance Revison:")

    self.label_title.pack()

    self.button_test = tk.Button(self.mainwindow, padx=54, pady=3, font=("Purisa",15), text="Take a Test", command=self.parent.test).pack()
    self.button_recentscore = tk.Button(self.mainwindow, font=("Purisa",15), text="View My Recent Scores", command=self.parent.recentscores).pack()
    self.button_help = tk.Button(self.mainwindow, padx=88, pady=3, font=("Purisa",15), text="Help", command=self.parent.help_mainwindow).pack()
    self.button_exit = tk.Button(self.mainwindow, padx=91, pady=3, font=("Purisa",15), text="Exit", command=self.parent.Exit).pack()
```

Everything works other than the padding between the widgets.
I have all the running files of this in a separate file as its a big project.
The padding in the widgets definition is just to shape them not move them on the frame. How can we add vertical padding between the buttons in a column?

Comment: I'm without python here to test, but IIRC you need to point a specific frame in tk.Button instead of self.mainwindow.

Comment: When you say "padding between the widgets", which widgets are you referring to? The frames? The buttons?

Comment: Vertical padding between the buttons so that the buttons are separated.

Comment: @CalebHeath: the vertical padding seems to work fine. For example, change pady to 90 for the help button and you'll see a large amount of vertical padding.

Comment: For me when I change that value all it does is shift all 4 widgets in one big block by the total amount of all of them it seems, it doesnt seem to pad each one separately so they are apart which is what im after. Here is an image of what I see when I change that value http://imgur.com/azeDgUq

Comment: I have a hard time believing that changing the pady value for the help button will yield the image you say it does, since the image does not show any vertical padding on the help button.

Comment: Thats the issue its just padding all 4 widgets no matter which value i change in this section:

self.frame_main.pack(pady=15)

self.frame_title.pack(anchor="c")
    
self.frame_test.pack(pady=15)
    
self.frame_recentscore.pack(pady=15)
    
self.frame_help.pack(pady=15)
    
self.frame_exit.pack(pady=15)

this is my problem it just pads all 4 widgets down by a value of "y", no matter which value I edit on that part of the code. Its as if the pady is actually acting on the frame in which the widgets are contained in rather than the widgets them selves.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use:

```
x = tkinter.Button(...)
x.pack(pady=8)
```

By the way `x = None` when you do:

```
x = tkinter.Button(...).pack()
```

It's a classic beginners mistake.

Comment: thank you that is exactly what I needed. It seems so simple now

Answer (score 2):

It appears you misunderstand how padding works. When you apply a `padx` or `pady` value to a widget, that padding only affects that one widget. For example, if you specify a `pady` value of 100 for the help button, *only the help button is affected*. If you specify `pady` value for a frame, that only affects how that frame is padded with respect to its parent.

As an example, if you want a padding of 20 pixels for every button, you must specify a pady value of 20 pixels for each and every button. If you want the buttons as a group to have padding *around the group*, you want to specify the padding for the frame.